# Cite author's name using IEEE style

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, ieeetran

Currently I am using `natbib` with `IEEEtran` as the bibliography style.

```
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

When citing, I want to sometimes refer to the author's name:
e.g. *“Scholtz [2] has argued. . . .”* (example taken from [here](http://www2.ece.gatech.edu/academic/courses/ece4007/ECE4007A/deliverables/proposal/2011spring/IEEE_citations/IEEE%20Citation%20Guidelines2.pdf))

However, I cannot find a way to achieve this: Neither `\citep{key}` nor `\citeauthor{key}` works.

Is there a way to do this except for manually writing down in the text (`Schlotz \cite{key} has argued...`)? Or is this maybe not acceptable for the IEEE style?

Comment: for IEEE you would be better off if you follow the recommended way which is using `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` and only use `\cite{....}` key.

Comment: Are you telling me to simply not use the author's name at all and write "[12] argues that..." instead? 
Because using the [cite package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) or not doesn't seem to have much to do with my question, though it might be helpful for displaying the output of `\cite{...}` better/prettier.

Comment: yes I am. Because your article will be retypeset by the publication office so you don't need to make it perfect. And cite package is recommended by the IEEE Trans. publication office. You can check the How_to_... file

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I use TexMaker

Cybercrime may threaten a person or a nation's security and financial health. Issues surrounding these types of crimes have become high-profile, particularly those regarding hacking, copyright infringement, unwarranted mass-surveillance, sextortion, child pornography, and child grooming\cite{yar2019cybercrime}.

This works.

Also, I add the following code in the bibliography file.

@book{yar2019cybercrime,
  title={Cybercrime and society},
  author={Yar, Majid and Steinmetz, Kevin F},
  year={2019},
  publisher={SAGE Publications Limited}
}

Comment: Please give an example of how the output looks like or how this is different from normal citations and why it works.